# jQuery - Need to remove the value on mouse leave but not on mouse enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `jquery.rateit.min.js` to make a star rating, I need to consider below 2 conditons:

1. On mouse leave the value(coming as rating good, average etc.) should be remove.
2. After clicking on star and than removing the mouse the value should not be remove.

Below is the code:

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="5" value="0" step="1" id="backing1">
<div class="rateit" id="rateitHover" data-rateit-backingfld="#backing1" data-rateit-step="1" > 
    <span class="tooltip" style="float:right; padding-left:10px;"></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var tooltipvalues = ['Bad', 'Poor', 'Average', 'Good', 'Excellent'];

    $("#rateitHover").bind('over', function (event, value) {
        $('.tooltip').text(tooltipvalues[value - 1]);
    });

    $("#rateitHover").bind('reset', function () {
        $('.tooltip').text(''); 
    });

    $("#rateitHover").bind('rated', function (event, value) {
        $('.tooltip').text('R: ' + tooltipvalues[value - 1]);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: put your code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? All I have done is bind a function to the mouseleave event.

```
$('#rateitHover').bind('mouseleave', function() {
    var v = $('#rateitHover').rateit('value');
    if (v == 0) {
        $('.tooltip').html('');
    } else {
        $('.tooltip').html('R: ' + tooltipvalues[v - 1]);
    }
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/9xrkr/

Comment: Yes this is what i need there is just one problem. When i select the star and mouse over on another stars its value doesn't remove on mouse leave.

Comment: But you said "After clicking on star and than removing the mouse the value should not be remove."

Comment: Yes.."After clicking on star and than removing the mouse the value should not be remove." but what happen when we clicked on star and at same time hover to another stars than only the click star value should be appear on mouse leave..

Comment: I've updated my answer. Now the tooltip is always "R: something" when you have a star clicked.

Comment: @user1798659 Good to hear. Please do not forget to mark your question as Answered.

Comment: @vegemite4me...I again need your help. now i want to use this star rating(input) several times in a page obviously with different ids. Please let me know how i do this..http://jsfiddle.net/9xrkr/

Answer (score 2):

Just use a flag for it:

```
var hasBeenClicked = false;

$('.stars').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    if(hasBeenClicked) {
        //let the stars value
    } else {
        //reset the stars
    }
});

$('.stars .star').on('click', function() {
    //set the rating
    hasBeenClicked = true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jonas, really appreciated, i am new to jquery it would be good if you write full code for me as i am unable to write the correct code.

Comment: In order to write complete code, we'll need more information such as "where is the value saved, an input field?". Best way is for you to create a JSFiddle so we can correct your code there.

Comment: Clicking the reset button (the no entry icon) of the RateIt plugin is not covered by this logic. You would need to set `hasBeenClicked` to `false` in that case.